# formula for Cell E4 , L4 and D4

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating a formula in which any one condition follows it should just put that value. Following is condition:-

1. E4=81810100 or 62810100 then it text as Automatic
2. E4=81810101 or 62810101 then it text as Adjustment
3. L4= 0 then it text as Valuation
4. D4= search(roy) then it text as Royalty
5. Otherwise it should be Accrual

But i am not getting Text as Valuation , Accrual or royalty.

```
=IF(E5=81810100,"Payables Automatic",IF(E5=81810101,"Payables Adjustment",IF(E5=62810100,"Receivables Automatic",IF(E5=62810101,"Receivables Adjustment",IF(L5=0,"Valuation",IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("roy",D5),0)>0,"Royalty Accrual","Accrual"))))))
```

Comment: A sample of the data would help.  My guess is that E4 always equals one of the four numbers, and therefore it never gets to testing L4 and D4, once it find a true it stops looking and returns the true.

Comment: @pnuts  its E4 or L4/D4... If L4/D4 is true then E4 does not matter. In case of absenc of L4/D4  E4 need to be seen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

If D4 contains `roy` result should be "Royalty Accrual",
else if L4 contains `0` (only) result should be "Valuation",
else if E4 contains (only) one of the four specific 8-digit numbers the results are as in OP,
else "Accrual".

Please try:

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("roy",D4)),IF(AND(LEFT(L4)="0"),"Valuation",IF(LEFT(E4,4)="6281","Receivables",IF(LEFT(E4,4)="8181","Payables","Accrual"))&IF(RIGHT(E4,4)="0100"," Automatic",IF(RIGHT(E4,4)="0101"," Adjustment",""))),"Royalty Accrual")
```

Comment: Worked.. Thanks for great help and sorting it.

Answer (score 0):

When all cell are empty

[image]

When `E4` = 81810101 or 62810101 
[image]

When `D4` = roy

[image]

When `L4` is equal to 0

[image]

Try this:

```
=IF(E4=81810100,"Payables Automatic",IF(E4=81810101,"Payables Adjustment",IF(E4=62810100,"Receivables Automatic",IF(E4=62810101,"Receivables Adjustment",IF(AND(LEN(L4)>0,L4=NUMBERVALUE(0)),"Valuation",IF(IFERROR(SEARCH("roy",D4),0)>0,"Royalty Accrual","Accrual"))))))
```

Comment: no its not working. Yes it is difficult to maintain but i have to use formula in any case.

Comment: @AtulVij, which part is not working? I have added some screenshot